# How to de-escape string in scala?

Tags: java, json, scala, escaping

I found many posts about escaping string but no about de-escaping one.

Using Scala Play, my controller accept a JSON as a request. I extract a string from it via:

```
val text: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = request.body.\("source")
```

If I print `text.toString` I get e.g.

```
"Hello\tworld\nmy name is \"ABC\""
```

How can I transform this escaped text into normal one? The result should look like

```
Hello    world
my name is "ABC"
```

Up to this point, I've tried an approach like it follows:

```
replaceAll("""\\t""", "\t")
```

However, creating all possible escaping rules may be too complicated. So my question is: How to do that easily? Possibly using standard library. Java solutions are also possible.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are [interpolations](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) which allow you to transform Strings into formatted and/or escaped sequences. These interpolations like `s"..."` or `f"..."` are handled in [StringContext](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.StringContext$).

It also offers a reverse function:

```
val es = """Hello\tworld\nmy name is \"ABC\""""
val un = StringContext treatEscapes es
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote. This method provides the requested result.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, contrary, I marked you post as an answer and gave an upvote. It works exactly as described. Thank you

Comment: I've actually meant the downvoter without leaving any comments. I'm glad that I could help you.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but a possible reason is that Scala string escape sequences are different from the JSON ones.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an answer for unescaping strings in general, but specifically for handling `JsValue`:

```
text match { 
  case JsString(value) => value
  case _ => // what do you want to do for other cases?
}
```

You can implement unescape in this way:

```
def unescapeJson(s: String) = JSON.parse('"' + s + '"') match {
  case JsString(value) => value
  case _ => ??? // can't happen
}
```

or use [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) from Apache Commons Lang (though this is a rather large dependency).

Comment: this should be probably comment only, whatever, good point, thanks :)

Comment: The other answers only deal with Scala escape sequences, which aren't the same as JSON escape sequences (`\/` is valid in JSON but not in Scala, octal escapes vice versa).

Comment: @petrbel I've actually added a couple more options :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the unescape method from scala standard library. 
Here is the [link](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.1/index.html#scala.xml.Utility$) to the documentation you will find the method right at the end of the "Value Members" part.

Comment: This one comes from `scala.xml` and is used for unescaping *HTML entities* not backslash unescaping.